# Could someone check my reasoning: Show that when $f$ and $g$ are continuous on...

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, and let $f(a)=g(a)$ and 
$0 \le f'(x)<g'(x)$ on $(a,b)$. Show that $\forall x\in (a,b]:f(x)<g(x)$.

**My work:**

Since $f$ and $g$ are both continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ the function **$C(x)=g(x)-f(x)$** is also continuous on

$[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

$C'(x)=g'(x)-f'(x)$ for which we know $C'(x)>0 \Longrightarrow C(x)$ is strictly crowing on $[a,b]$.

So,

$\forall x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]:(x_1<x_2)\Longrightarrow (C(x_1)<C(x_2)\Longleftrightarrow g(x_1)-f(x_1)<g(x_2)-f(x_2)\Longleftrightarrow f(x_2)-f(x_1)<g(x_2)-g(x_1))$

If we now take the fact that  $g(a)=f(a)$ and let $x_1=a$ in our inequation  we get:

$\forall x_1,x_2 \in [a,b]:(x_1<x_2)\Longrightarrow (f(x_2)-f(x_1)<g(x_2)-g(x_1))$

$f(x_2)-f(a)<g(x_2)-g(a)\Longleftrightarrow f(x_2)<g(x_2)$

Which now finally tells us that $\forall x \in (a,b]:f(x)<g(x)$

It would be nice if you could give me some constructive feedback if I made wrong conclusions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning seems perfect to me. But you could've skipped half the proof by saying that $C$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$ and that $C(a)=0$.